# Python zlib to decompress gzipped data

Tags: python, zlib

If I have the following data set,

```
a 10
a 23
a  1
a  1
a  1
b 22
b 33
b  1
b  1
```

and someone gzips it using `gzip` in a Unix terminal into `data.gz`.

How could I use the zlib module to decompress it? I know the gzip module is an option, and it appears that gzip calls zlib, but I would like to know how to do this directly. The reason I am interested is zlib, is that gzip is really slow for the large files I work with. Usually, I use `zcat` to decompress files and read records using `sys.stdin`. However, I'm looking for another way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try that?

Using the example you gave

```
In [4]: import gzip

In [5]: f = gzip.open('words.gz','rb')

In [6]: file_content = f.read()

In [7]: f.close()

In [8]: print(file_content)
```

Comment: Didn't work. `echo "words" | gzip > words.gz` and saw `UnrecognizedFormat: Not a recognized archive type: words.gz`

Comment: hi @Jon, I'm using Python3

Comment: I'm aware of the availability of `gzip`, and am also aware that `gzip` calls `zlib`. However, I am specifically interested in understanding how `zlib` works in the background for `gzip`.